# CRM 2016 on-permise sitemap

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'd like to know if there is a way to open another webpage in new window just like it was in 4.0 and 2011 from sitemap button. I know that i can call webresource with javascript in it taht will open webpage but in that case after opening webpage in new window it leaves me with empty page as current and because of that it's not an option.

Kind regards,
JD

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go the web resource route.  After it calls window.open, you could then have the original window navigate to the home page.  So, after calling window.open, the web resource would do something like this:

```js
parent.window.location.href = "https://yourorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx";
```

**Update based on your comment**

To have the user taken back to the previous page, do: `window.top.history.back()`

Comment: Tried this but it opens main CRM page and i want it to stay on last opened CRM page. Tried history.back() also but this gets me to weird refresh loops.